# Not displaying in IE8?

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I've got a puzzling problem in that a certain bit of HTML displays fine in all modern browsers and IE7, but completely fails in IE8. I've racked my mind as to which CSS could remedy this problem but I've come up short every time.

If you look at [this link](http://tatumreid.com/peter-kate-wedding-photography-essex/) in chrome, near the bottom you'll notice FB/Twitter share buttons, but if you look at the corresponding space in IE8, there's nothing. Could someone please check it out and let me know, I'm stumped...

The CSS code is:

```
body div.mr_social_sharing_wrapper {
  clear: both !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 960px !important;
  z-index: 2000 !important;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  float: left;
}

span.mr_social_sharing, 
span.mr_social_sharing_top {
  float: left;
}
```

And yes, I know using !important is poor form; it was inherited and not by choice :)

Comment: I can see them when browsing in IE8?

Comment: Don't have IE8, but if I set IE9 to document/browser mode on IE8 the links show up fine. Only thing I can think of then (something that I always forget) is IE caching: hit the dev tools in IE and set caching to 'Always refresh from server'. If it's not that hopefully someone else will have a suggestion...

Comment: Really? Neither me not the owner of the website can? Is your browser set to IE8 standards?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm running xp with IE8 and despite running an uncached version, it's still hidden. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be solved by removing the display styles (you had both `display: inline-block` and `display:block`) and `float: left` from  `span.mr_social_sharing_top`.

If there was a good reason for needing the display styles (trouble in other browsers?) you could also add fixed widths to these spans to solve the problem.

Comment: My hero! You've saved my hairline! Thank you so much.